# Unable to log into SSRS through SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2016

I am trying to log into SSRS with SSMS to make a custom role. I am using my domain admin account that is able to log into the database engine side of things fine but when I try to go to reporting services I get "The username or password is not valid or you do not have permissino to access this server"

Comment: did you configure report server to use Forms Authentication? and use full URL like: https://server.domain.com/reportserver

Comment: That helped me out, we had to use basic authentication so I needed to use that and authenticate with my domain\username and password!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The report server is configure to use SSL, and the report server is configure to use **Basic Authentication**.

Basic authentication is defined in the HTTP protocol and can only be used to authenticate HTTP requests to the report server.

If you use Basic authentication, use Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) to encrypt user account information before it is sent across the network. SSL provides an encrypted channel for sending a connection request from the client to the report server over an HTTP TCP/IP connection

If we configure the report server to use Forms (custom) Authentication over SSL, we will get the error "The username or password is not valid or you do not have permission to access this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.RSClient)" while connecting to the report server from SQL Server Manager Studio(SSMS) using server alias.

To fix the issue, please use the full URL and authenticate with my **domain\username and password**.

For example,

> https://server.domain.com/reportserver

Comment: Thanks again, I only needed to enter the server name in SSMS, change it to basic authentication. Unfortunately when I select always use SSL it does not work.